# I am a newbie to the MySQL-python connector coding, specifics given below

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I need to connect a variable to a search condition where I am looking to retrieve specific details from a table:

```
purchase = input("Please enter your Transaction ID(Found in the format - Letter-Number-Letter-Letter-Number, like A9BH1): ")
```

Here, I need 'Purchase' as the condition in

```
  sql = "select * from 4wps where T_ID = "
  cursor.execute(sql)
  result = cursor.fetchall()
```

I do not know how to enter 'purchase' into the above sample after 'T_ID ='. I have followed a friend's code, but he apparently copied it from somewhere.

I am in 12th in India, CBSE, and this is for a project, and therefore I cannot use anything advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), you can (and should!) pass in parameters into your query using either a tuple or a dictionary:

```
cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=False)
```

For your query, you could do it this way.

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM 4wps WHERE T_ID = %s'
cursor.execute(sql, (purchase,))
```

or this way

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM 4wps WHERE T_ID = %(tid)s'
params = {'tid': purchase}
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

in both cases the connector will put the contents of your `purchase` variable into the query and will automatically add any quotes for a string if necessary. Using this kind of technique is usually preferred because it offers some protection against SQL injection attacks.

I'm not sure if this would work, but imagine if a user typed this:

```
Please enter your Transaction ID
(Found in the format - Letter-Number
-Letter-Letter-Number, like A9BH1): 
      (DROP TABLE 4wps)
```

Maybe your data table would be destroyed.

Another humorous example of SQL injection is [Bobby Tables](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom) which is explained again [here](https://bobby-tables.com/about)

Answer (score 0):

Just add it this way:

```
sql = "select * from 4wps where T_ID = '" + purchase + "'"
```

Comment: here, ID is 'purchase', right? Also, thanks!

Comment: Welcome dear. yes can be the id of anything a person, a purchase

Comment: Rafa: It might be worth making a mention of SQL injection here. I'm not familiar with Python, but I assume the standard MySQL drivers allow parameter binding?