# Is there any way to call particular items in a list using their index number inn python?

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am asking this in relation to a project I am working on, highlighted in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71152973/i-am-a-newbie-to-the-mysql-python-connector-coding-specifics-given-below). I have the following code to ask questions and take the input as answers, logging them in a separate list:

```
     questions = ["Please enter your car's brand name: ", "Please enter your car's model name: ", "Please enter your car's year: ","Please enter yes/no for whether or not your car has scratches/dents: ","Please enter quoted price given by representative: "]
     answers = []
     for q in questions:
         a = input(q)
         answers.append(a)
     print(a)
```

The problem is, I get None, None as the answer as
None
None
Whenever it is run in conjunction with the code I am working on. Please point out any mistake I am making, as, on its own, the code works the way I want it to work in the aforementioned other code.

Edit: perhaps I should clarify: I am looking for a way to enter the individual elements into a table in MySQL via the connector. I have the following code hashed out, but I am struggling with actually entering the elements:

```
sql = "insert into new_purchases \nValues('element1','element2','element3','element4');"
```

Here,  elements 1-4 are the elements of list answers and are being entered into the table new_purchases.

Comment: Please provide the MINIMAL example. All those lines of code do not help to understand your problem.

Comment: I  have done that, please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Shouldn't you print `answers`, not `a`?

Answer (score 0):

**YES**, You definitely call a particular item in a list by using their index number.

Minor fix in your code.

```
questions = ["Please enter your car's brand name: ", "Please enter your car's model name: ", "Please enter your car's year: ","Please enter yes/no for whether or not your car has scratches/dents: ","Please enter quoted price given by representative: "]
answers = []
for q in questions:
    a = input(q)
    answers.append(a)
print(answers)
```

if you call a particular item in a list then simply use this code snippet.

```
index = 0 # 0, 1, 2, ...., n
print(questions[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to replace the `print(a)` with `print(answers)`.